# Ruby-debug color?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-debug

For the people who use ruby-debug, do you do anything to get it to output in color?  I'm setting up wirble right now to colorize my irb, but it's not going to colorize pretty print (which, I believe comes from ruby-debug instead of irb)

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite of ruby-debug [rb-trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki) (for a patched 1.9.2) and [rbx-trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rbx-trepanning/wiki) (for rubinius 1.2.x) support colorized listing and even assembly output via the CodeRay gem.

See https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki/Terminal-Colors and 
https://github.com/rocky/rbx-trepanning/wiki/Terminal-Colors

There is nothing in ruby-debug right now. If there is sufficient demand, that code could be back-ported to ruby-debug. But it would mean a new version of the source-code line caching gem linecache.

Comment: I'm on 1.8.7, but I'll keep this in mind for when I upgrade.  Thanks!

Comment: You most likely mean **MRI** 1.8.7. Rubinius is also at 1.8.7. (And JRuby supports both 1.8.7 and 1.9.x)

Comment: I'm not sure--I think my version of ruby came with my Ubuntu install (10.10), if not, then it was a part of my Rails 3.0.4 install